# Data cached in plugin controller via CacheService won't expire

Tags: plugin-development, cache, plugin-elementapi

My cache won't expire. This is effectively my code:

```
    $template = (isset($params['template']) ? $params['template'].'?'.$config['pageParam'].'='.$pageParam : null);

    if(craft()->cache->get($template))
    {
        echo craft()->cache->get($template);
        craft()->end();
    }

    if(craft()->config->get('enableTemplateCaching'))
    {
        craft()->cache->set($template, $JsonValue, 'P1D');
    }
```

The cache saves just fine but when I forward the clock on my server a few days ahead and refresh the page it's still using the cached data. I've also tried actually waiting a few days in case it was using another clock but that didn't help either.

Is there something I'm missing? I figure Craft or the Yii Framework will take care of expiring the cache after the one day period set (P1D). I don't see any methods to check the date of the cache or anything where I could manually intervene.

For what it's worth I'm using [theolampert's fork](https://github.com/theolampert/ElementAPI) of the ElementAPI plugin which adds caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug in the plugin.

The 3rd `$expire` parameter when calling set [states](https://craftcms.com/classreference/etc/cache/FileCache#set-detail):

> The number of seconds in which the cached value will expire. 0 means never expire.

But it's passing in the PHP time format notation.  I'd suggest contacting the author of the plugin.